# Genoise vs whipped egg whites - which makes cakes fluffier?

Tags: baking, eggs, cake

When making a cake utilising all the leavening agents including creamed butter and sugar as well as baking powder and soda, would there be any difference if I were to include whipped egg whites vs foamed whole eggs?

Which one would provide a fluffier / lighter texture to the cake?

Comment: This question is hard to answer. What is better? depends what you are trying to make. They both are used as leavening in different styles of cake. You are essentially asking "What is better? Pound cake or angel food cake". Of course the answer to that is angel food cake and so the answer to your question is egg whites. (This answer may be a bit too subjective to be useful)

Comment: Also, beaten egg whites are going to be difficult to integrate in any meaningful way with creamed butter. And if you are determined to use all leavening agents then don't forget yeast as well.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.   I'll be more specific with my question.   Which of them would result in a more lighter and fluffier cake? If not that, then at the very least there must be advantages and disadvantages to using each method right?  Thank you again.

Comment: Also, wouldn't yeast be counterproductive in a cake? It does tend to result in a more chewier texture.

Comment: Well if you're using creamed butter, it's neither a genoise nor an angel food cake. If I were you, I would look at the established cake types rather than trying to come up with a new one.

Comment: If you want to add more details you can [edit] your question, it's more visible than comments. Check also [ask] and the [tour] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: What if I were to combine the two together by beating egg yolks till ribbon stage and then whipping the egg whites?  Also, thanks for the suggestions Luciano.   I'm still finding my way around this site at the moment!

Comment: And to Aris,  you are correct however I would still like to know the answer just to satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Génoise is always made with whipped white eggs for maximum fluff. No matter how long you whisk your whole eggs, they will never get close to the consistency of whipped egg whites.
Found an interesting comparison video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCdOU-1sjO0

Now if you make your cake with foamed eggs I'm sure it will be good, but it won't be a génoise anymore.

Regarding the use of butter, there are two schools, some use a bit of melted butter, others don't use any butter at all. I personally never use butter because I think it is lighter and fluffier without it, and generally I fill my génoise with ganache, so that brings the fatty element to the cake. However it is always melted butter, I have never seen a recipe using creamed butter, and indeed I think it will make your batter heavier and your cake will be denser.
But if you ever try please let me know!